# Huge Lags using UDP. Why?

Tags: network-programming, udp

I have build an MMO game and I'm having a lot of lags when lot of people are connected. I'm using UDP and TCP packets. the TCP seeme to work really good, throgh the UDP comes after a delay of 5 seconds sometimes. What may cause this? I'm using MongoDB and sending packets 30 times per second per client. Thanks.

Comment: I'm intersting in a follow-up to this question. Did you get it resolved? Were any of the below answers correct? Thx

Answer (score 0):

UDP protocol does not provide guarantie for the package delivery. So your problem may be in this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: I have checked for it and it seems all the packets are coming but in a delay of 5 seconds. When first starting the server, it's all OK. After 2 hours, 2 seconds. after 5 hours, 5 seconds delay, etc. All (most..) of the packets are coming, but in a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: your UDP packet receive path involves allocating memory, and you leak that memory. The more packets are received, the longer it takes to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also guessing here, but the situation could be that your application is polling for UDP packets every *n* milliseconds (like, if your FPS is 20 then *n* would be 50ms).

Now the guess is that during this time your PC receives a lot of UDP packets and they get stacked up by your operating system. Then, when you get to poll for these packets, either you or the operating system don't clear the stack at once. A bigger stack might then mean bigger lag.

I think I've read somewhere that even some routers try to be smart and stack up UDP packets. But I'm unable to find the page where I saw it.

I've posted a similar question here:

[Router gets unresponsive when using UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588697/router-gets-unresponsive-when-using-udp)

and the above is my current theory :), unfortunately I don't yet know how to work around it. One possibility that comes to my mind is to use a separate thread that would react instantly to network requests instead of polling the network every *n* ms.